# Perhaps A Human Is Not Quite Right

Tags: wordplay

Solve each line, and find the final 6 letter answer, which will be not quite...

Perhaps a human is not quite right
A hum is not quite over
An insect is not quite an opening
A nap is not quite a female animal
An organ is not quite bad weather
A pole is not quite on a tree
A seasoning is not quite showy
A chemical state is not quite a surprise reaction
Stomped is not quite kept
To teach again is not quite to prevent
An artillery is not quite general law
Wound is not quite preserved

*Edited a few for specificity. Sorry Silenus!!!*
*Edited the stomped clue for specificity. Sorry YowE3k!*

Comment: :( Super sorry I had to do the edit. Like you said, 'savaged' is a bit of a stretch indeed, but it's better to make an edit so that the ambiguity is gone entirely

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer:

> ALMOST   ([@Glen O](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9289/glen-o) solved the meta)

Explanation:

> Each line clues two words which differ by a single letter. There are 12 clues in total.
>
>  The discrepant letters are:
>
>      TRUZBKNPMSNL.
>
>  As noticed by [@Glen O](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9289/glen-o), we can parse this string into the following pairs:
>
>     | TR | *U* | ZB | **K** | NP | **M** *S* | NL | =
>
>     TR US ZB KM NP NL.
>
>  Now, looking at the letters between these pairs, we get STALOM, an anagram of ALMOST.
>
>  The answer was clued by OP's explicitly telling us the answer is NOT QUITE (a synonym of ALMOST).

The clues:

```
Perhaps a human is not quite right
```

> MORTAL [human] is not quire MORAL [right]   [@Bailey M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11475/bailey-m)

```
A hum is not quite over
```

> DRONE [hum] is note quite DONE [over]   [@Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304/mike-q)

```
An insect is not quite an opening
```

> MOTH [an insect] is not quite MOUTH [an opening]   [@Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304/mike-q)

```
A nap is not quite a female animal
```

> DOZE [nap] is not quite DOE [a female animal]

```
An organ is not quite bad weather
```

> BRAIN [an organ] is not quite RAIN [bad weather]

```
A pole is not quite on a tree
```

> BAR [pole] is not quite BARK [on a tree]

```
A seasoning is not quite showy
```

> GARNISH [seasoning] is not quite GARISH [showy]

```
A chemical state is not quite a surprise reaction
```

> GAS [a state] is not quite GASP [a surprise reaction]

```
Stomped is not quite kept
```

> STORMED [stomped] is not quite STORED [kept]   [@YowE3K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/27290/yowe3k) (confirmed by OP)

```
To teach again is not quite to prevent
```

> RETRAIN [to teach again] is not quite RESTRAIN [to prevent]   [@Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304/mike-q)

```
An artillery is not quite general law
```

> CANNON [artillery] is not quite CANON [general law]

```
Wound is not quite preserved
```

> CURLED [wound] is not quite CURED [preserved]    [@Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304/mike-q)

Comment: @MikeQ, maybe... but that breaks the pattern of the words differing in length by one. Let's see if we can find another example like that.

Comment: @MikeQ both of your guesses are really close! Try to make them fit the pattern of Silenus' answers.

Comment: The form might be: PRExxx --> RExxx

Comment: @MikeQ, yes but drop the -*ing*s.

Comment: Ooh. Interesting. I think there's a word slightly better than 'RETAIN' for stop... that definition doesn't quite match up

Comment: I may reword the retrain clue for specificity

Comment: @YowE3K, yeah the tense is off. It would have to be *sore / stored*, which has an extra letter.

Comment: @Mike that's better than my COILED / OILED

Comment: savaged / salvaged?  For stomped / saved.  (Again a bit of a stretch.)

Comment: I think it works perfectly.

Comment: Try mortal/moral for the first one

Comment: @BaileyM :) Nice work

Comment: re: stomped, someone in this comment thread got one of the words right

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper Sounds like it might be retained then.

Comment: I think the original comment must have been deleted. I can see the word being referred to, but not where it originated from. It might even have been one of your comments @YowE3K

Comment: Moi ?!?!  Coming up with even half of a correct answer!?!?  Couldn't be!

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper Based on your last comment, I can only think of stormed /stored.  But stormed seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Heh, oh well, that *is* the intended answer... ah well

Comment: Cool! Just the meta left. The Trump SNL thing definitely is just a coincidence. I don't mix my puzzles with politics :) Think about how many letters you have, and how long the answer will need to be.

Comment: Am I the only one who suspects the final answer is "almost"? I can't justify it within the puzzle, but it's certainly "not quite".

Comment: @GlenO, that's an excellent conjecture. You should try to make it work with the characters we have.

Comment: Got it - the letters are between pairs of letters. If list off the letters in "almost", but instead show the letters either side, you have ZB/KM/LN/NP/RT/SU. Now look at the letters we have, and compare. They're all there, with two Ns as required.

Comment: @GlenO, well done, but I wish the logic of the grouping in the 12-character string was more regular. Starting on the left, each pair is broken from the next by an unpaired letter, until you get to `MS`. I guess you're supposed to notice that a few of the pairs are one letter apart and then deduce that `U` pairs with `S` and `K` with `M`.

Comment: I actually ordered the list alphabetically by the first item being compared. I was intending for it to be noticeable that all the letters were fairly close together apart from B and Z, this leading to a conjecture that B pairs with Z. And then it would kind of make sense to take the letter 'between' them, which is A. There's only one way to put the letters into pairs where they are 'not quite' but 'almost' the same letter.